# How were the monster detectors created?

Tags: sweet-home

In the second season of *Sweet Home*, the military appears to have devices that detect the presence of monsters in the stadium. From the way that people talk about them, they appear to actually detect *monsters*, as opposed to being, say, proximity sensors set up on the perimeter.

This is notable, since there do not appear to be any monster-related artifacts, in general, with the only other candidate being a supposed vaccine created by Dr. Lim, whose existence has yet to be confirmed. How were these monster-detecting devices created and what are they?

Comment: The TV Tropes page mentions that "Much like in Silent Hill, monsters create radio interference that can be heard if you dial out with a cell phone and listen by plugging in headphones.". I suspect that it's probably built off of a similar idea, but more directly checking for frequency interference.